# Deploying create-react-app --template-typescript to gh pages

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, github-pages

I have a problem with deploying typescript react app, all I get is the most outer  element from the MainTemplate.tsx file, I should be seeing a logging screen, there are no routes available for me that I have available locally. Also, I have done npm run build many times now, and it is saying that my last deploy was 14 hours ago, how can I refresh it? I tried to change my deply script to this one but did not work:

"deploy": "./node_modules/gh-pages/bin/gh-pages-clean.js && gh-pages -d build"

this is my package.json

```
{
  "homepage": "https://dziekonskik.github.io/project-money-front",
  "name": "project-money-front",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": false,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3000",
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^1.2.3",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^24.9.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.14",
    "@types/react": "^16.14.8",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.13",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.16",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.9",
    "aws-amplify": "^4.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "gsap": "^3.7.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
    "styled-reset": "^4.3.4",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "./node_modules/gh-pages/bin/gh-pages-clean.js && gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
    "gh-pages": "^3.2.3"
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry not npm run build but deploy, actually I did them both many times over

Comment: Did you check this section is cra doc: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#notes-on-client-side-routing ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @yume_chan changing BrowserRouter component to HashRouter did the job. Also there was no need to modify deploy script when I changed back to

"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"

worked as well with HashRouter

Regards!